# mongo update $set value copied from array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can someone show me the syntax for setting the value of a field from an array in the same document?  That is, given:

```
{ "MyArray" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

I need to update it to

```
{ "MyArray" : [ 1, 2, 3 ], "NewValue" : 3 }
```

Comment: you didn't actually set MyArray in your example.  Do you mean you want to $set a different field Array2: [1,2,3]?

Comment: If you just want to get the last value of the array: `db.test.find( {"MyArray": {"$exists":true}}, { "MyArray": { $slice: -1 }})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB's `update` does not support setting a field to a value from the same document. You can only pass in constants.

Comment: Jesse's right.  But, I found a way to do it using forEach():  db.test.find({"MyArray":{$exists:true},"NewValue":{$exists:false}}).forEach(
 function(f) {
  f.NewValue = f.MyArray.slice(-1)[0];
  db.test.save(f)
 }
)`

Comment: This will totally work, but be aware that each document must be transferred from server to client and back, and there will be race conditions if another process is updating the same documents concurrently.

Comment: @JoelSherriff do you have a reference for that? Is this a feature or is there hope this might change in the future? I was hoping for something like `UPDATE users SET name=firstname + " " + lastname, firstname=null, lastname=null` and assume that the problem at hands is not the array but it's a more general kind of issue?

Comment: The tracking ticket is here, it's a planned feature but not scheduled: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1765